# Program Hangs Half of the Time

Tags: c

I have written the following program to display random character things (inspiration from `Predator` the movie):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char line0[100];
char line1[100];
char line2[100];
char line3[100];
char line4[100];
char line5[100];

void addImage(short *image);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");

  while (1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      short image[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

      short lines = arc4random() % 10;

      for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++) {
        short pos;
        do {
          pos = arc4random() % 8;
        } while (image[pos] != 0);
        image[pos] = 1;
      }

      addImage(image);
    }

    printf("%s\n", line0);
    printf("%s\n", line1);
    printf("%s\n", line2);
    printf("%s\n", line3);
    printf("%s\n", line4);
    printf("%s\n", line5);

    sleep(1);

    sprintf(line0, "");
    sprintf(line1, "");
    sprintf(line2, "");
    sprintf(line3, "");
    sprintf(line4, "");
    sprintf(line5, "");

    printf("\e[6F");
  }

  return 0;
}

void addImage(short *image) {
  snprintf(line0, sizeof(line0), "%s _______  ", line0);
  snprintf(line1, sizeof(line1), "%s|       | ", line1);
  snprintf(line2, sizeof(line2), "%s| %c %c %c | ", line2, image[0] ? '\\' : ' ', image[1] ? '-' : ' ', image[2] ? '/' : ' ');
  snprintf(line3, sizeof(line3), "%s| %c %c %c | ", line3, image[3] ? '|' : ' ', image[4] ? '-' : ' ', image[5] ? '|' : ' ');
  snprintf(line4, sizeof(line4), "%s| %c %c %c | ", line4, image[6] ? '/' : ' ', image[7] ? '-' : ' ', image[8] ? '\\' : ' ');
  snprintf(line5, sizeof(line5), "%s|_______| ", line5);
}

/* _______
  |       |
  | \ - / |
  | | - | |
  | / - \ |
  |_______|
*/
```

The problem is that when I run it sometimes the program hangs before even the clear screen line (`printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");`) is called. Other times the program will change the characters one or twice and then hang. Why is the program stalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial printf is not printed because stdout is buffered in C. You have to put `fflush(stdout);` after printf. Then the program may loop infinitely, because you assign a random value in the range 0-9 to `lines` and then try to generate up to `lines` unique numbers in the range 0-7. If `lines` == 9, you will loop infinitely.

Comment: Didn't need the `fflush` but changing the line to `short lines = arc4random() % 9;` solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `short lines = arc4random() % 8;` would be better.

Comment: But there are a total of 9 possible slots. Wouldn't that all the slots could never be filled?

Comment: @cabellicar123 9 slots can not be filled by 8 unique integer numbers in the range 0-7.

Comment: It would be better then to increase the `pos` range to `0-8` then?